# Updating progress bar during loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, swift2

I have two controllers. In the first I have a progress bar and there is a request that I get data and loop. I need to update a bar that is on the first controller during the loop. The problem is that even if it does not update a loop, a slash is only updated when a method execution finishes.

FirstView:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
    for i in 0 ..< JSON.count {

        autoreleasepool{
            count = count + 1
            if count >= percentage {
                progress = progress + 1
                //This notification executes the method that makes the update in the first view
                NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("ProgressNotification", object: nil, userInfo: ["label":"Clientes", "progress" : progress])
                count = 0
            }
        }

    }
}
```

SecondView:

//Method that will update the toolbar

```
func addProgress(notification:NSNotification){
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.progressBar.setProgress(CGFloat.init(notification.userInfo!["progress"] as! Int), animated: true)
        self.progressLabel.text = notification.userInfo!["label"] as? String
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your constant switching of threads and the detour over the notification service. However, you are supposed to set your progress to a float between 0.0 an 1.0. 
What you are doing is that you are sort of casting int values from 1 to JSON.count to float. Therefore your progress vallue is always 1.0 or more.

Better use something like `.setProgress(CGFloat.init(JSON.count) / CGFloat.init(i))`.

Do both, cast your ints to floats and make sure that the divisio is a float division not an integer division. (integer divisions will evaluate to 0 or 1 or more but noting in between.)